# nodejs download fails due to invalid link (Protocol switch unsafe) Liferay 7

Tags: node.js, reactjs, macos, liferay, portlet

failures using Gradle v.6 + Workspace / liferay 7.2 , Here is the stacktrace exception of the first build command ​​​​​:

> Task :downloadNode FAILED
> Trying to download http://mirrors.lax.liferay.com/nodejs.org/dist/v10.15.1/node-v10.15.1-linux-x64.tar.gz to /home/jenkins/.liferay/mirrors/nodejs.org/dist/v10.15.1/node-v10.15.1-linux-x64.tar.gz.tmp
> Trying to download http://nodejs.org/dist/v10.15.1/node-v10.15.1-linux-x64.tar.gz to /home/jenkins/.liferay/mirrors/nodejs.org/dist/v10.15.1/node-v10.15.1-linux-x64.tar.gz.tmp
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':downloadNode'.

> Redirection detected from http to https. Protocol switch unsafe, not allowed.

Any good FIX, thanks in advance..?

Answer (score 0):

Edit :

problem solved by adding this to the build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    plugins.withId("com.liferay.node") {
        node.global = true
        node.nodeUrl = node.nodeUrl.replace("http:", "https:")
        System.out.println(node.nodeUrl)
    } }
```